# Form AJAX submit symfony doesn't work

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony

I don't understand why my AJAX submit doesn't work.

I have two forms in my the controller:

```
$intervento = new Intervento();
$form = $this->createForm(InterventoType::class, $intervento);

$form->handleRequest($request);

$user = new User();
$form_user = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
$form_user->handleRequest($request);

if ($form_user->isSubmitted() && $form_user->isvalid()) {
    $response = new Response();
    return $this->json(array('risultato' => ' ok'));
}

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isvalid()) { }

return $this->render('interventi/collaudo.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'form_utente' => $form_user->createView(),
));
```

In my twig file I start the form and it works:

```
{{form_start(form_utente,{'attr':{'id':'form-utente'}})}}
    .....
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s4">
                    <input type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{form_end(form_utente)}}
</div>
```

In my JavaScript file:

```
$('#form-utente').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data['risultato']);
            // setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = "#" }, 500);
            // setTimeout(function() { $("#form-stufa").click() }, 500);
        },
        error: function(){
        }
    });
});
```

I also have another AJAX call in this JavaScript, but I don't this gives the problem.

The submit button sometimes returns `Error 500`, sometimes an `undefined` alert.

I think it doesn't go to submit in the controller but I don't know why.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show information from browser console or symfony toolbar about request/response?

Comment: console is empty or Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Do you use dev env?

Comment: http://localhost/app.php      -> *prod* environment
http://localhost/app_dev.php  -> *dev* environment

Comment: localhost:8000  so dev environment but i don't  have response now

Comment: why you don't use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html) for js urls. You need expose your routing.

Comment: alert(form.attr('action'));  is undefined .. is normal???

Comment: i try also var path_utente =Routing.generate('cat_collaudo');
        var form =$(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:form.attr('method'),
            url:path_utente,      but now ajax don't start

Comment: ok using Routing.generate('cat_collaudo') it work ..tank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html) for js urls. You need expose your routing.